# MousePositioningWnd in Taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-11

Every time I start my laptop this application starts (see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vChwm.png)) and can be seen on the taskbar.
Does anyone know why and how I can remove it?

Don't want to have to close it every time manually.

[image: MousePositioningWnd]

In the picture, the first thing below the name is "Attach to taskbar", the second "Close all windows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commandline for the process is the following C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\LenovoDisplayControlCenterService\MousePositioningWnd.exe

I have a Lenovo monitor and installed the Lenovo Display Control Center App to check for firmware updates. Now uninstalling ;-) A tip is to add command line column in Task Manager.

Comment: thank you, the tip is very helpful :)